# If we built one hundred 3m telescopes and point them to a single star what would be the final resolution?

Tags: telescope

We'll mount all of them in a same location and connect them to each other (like VLT) so they will combined all the results and will produce some staggering images however my question is, would they be able to produce an image close to the resolution of a 300m optical telescope?

Comment: θ = 1.22 (λ/D) where θ is the angular resolution(radians), λ is the wavelength of light and D is the diameter of the lens' aperture.

Comment: @user6760 That's the key to the answer, just write it up with some explanation and post it as an answer. Don't forget to explain how the "aperture" is determined for interferometry telescopes and the difficulties in using optical interferometry.

Comment: @Donald.McLean I'm afraid my knowledge in this area is limited, I hope you may give some insights on interferometry thanks.

Comment: Wikipedia has some good articles that talk about the issues (such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronomical_interferometer ). I think the main things are the incredible precision required and how the number of mirrors involved cause significant attenuation of the signal, severely limiting which objects that can be imaged in this way.

Comment: Found this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6TY51JsH4Q&index=14&list=PLX2gX-ftPVXVpN_nZlZ0N1sSYTv0xYoTX  Thanks everybody.

Comment: Would whomever voted to reopen mind adding a comment to explain why?  It seems like the duplicate listed is accurate.